# Generating filename using given string

Tags: java, android, encode

I want a solution in java that (encoding) generates filename from the given string and
(decoding) with giving generated filename returns the string that we used to generate filename.

This is what i want.

```
String myId = "asd"

String encodedFileName = GenerateFileName(myId);
String GenerateFileName(String key){
        return encodedString(key);
}
String decodeFileName(String FileName){
        return decodedString(FileName);
}

encodedFileName == "SomeEncodedString";



String decoded = decodeFileName(encodedFileName);
decoded == "asd";
```

Comment: Ok, what you did so far?

Comment: You mean hashing? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you want to encode filename if it contains special character?

Comment: i did nothing. all i want is like base64 with this different that doesnt contains characters we cant use as filename like quotes or slashes

Comment: i have tried base64 but sometimes it returns string containig slashes can't use as filenames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String name = "FileName";
String extension = ".txt";
String fileName = name.concat(extension);
```

Comment: no! i could do this but i wanted more professional way. an encoded string

Comment: what do you mean by an encoded string

Comment: i edited my question. it may make you clear

Comment: you can use an arithmetic expression on each character of the string to encode it and use inverse of that expression while decoding

Comment: thanks for reply. i found my solution